# (ultrasonic sensor code : No such file or directory)

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors

I'm beginning in Arduino I do not understand what the error means. Please tell me where I can find the resources to understand it and allow the code to compile.

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>
#include <Ultrasonic.h>

Ultrasonic ultrasonic(11,10);
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

int i;

void setup() {
    mySwitch.enableTransmit(4);  
}

void loop() {  
    i = ultrasonic.Ranging(CM);
    mySwitch.send(i, 24);
    delay(100); 
}
```

> Arduino: 1.8.7 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> 433mhz-lcd-water-level-transmitter:2:24: error: Ultrasonic.h: No such
>   file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> exit status 1 Ultrasonic.h: No such file or directory
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: Did you install the library?

Comment: I did add an ultrasonic library but have the same error

Comment: Thanks for all my problem is solved download ultrasonic code here https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/ultrasonic i found another library ultrasonic solve my first problem(Ultrasonic.h: No such file or directory) but then have another error... it say(class Ultrasonic' has no member named 'Ranging').... in this time i changed some of my code and now working good my code after solve include include Ultrasonic ultrasonic(11,10); // (Trig PIN,Echo PIN) RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch(); int i; void setup() { mySwitch.enableTransmit(4); } void loop() { Ultrasonic ultrasonic(11,10,3000); // (Tri

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says:

> Ultrasonic.h: No such file or directory

The file `Ultrasonic.h` can't be found.

Anything in your code that starts `#include...` is usually a *library*. These are third party pieces of software that you have to obtain and install into the relevant location (See [Installing Additional Arduino Libraries](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries)).

Some libraries are bundled with the IDE, and some are available through the "library manager" in the IDE. However most aren't, and you will have to get used to finding those libraries and installing them.

The location you got your example code from will most likely link you to where to find the relevant libraries to get the code working.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error means that the Arduino IDE (assuming that is what your are using) did not find 'Ultrasonic.h' in a folder named 'libraries' within your Arduino sketch folder. (Some libraries are contained in other places within the IDE's executable, but putting your additional libraries in '.../libraries' keeps everything easy to find and maintain).

Go to `File | Preferences` (in Windows or Linux) or `Arduino | Preferences` (Mac). The top box in that dialog is the path to your sketch folder. That folder should contain one called 'libraries'.

The libraries folder should have a folder for each library, so in this case, there should be a folder named 'Ultrasonic', containing files 'Ultrasonic.h' and 'Ultrasonic.cpp'. There may be other items in there as well, perhaps an Examples folder, a 'keywords.txt' file (helps the IDE with syntax coloring), a text file with release notes, etc., but the important structure is

```
[path/to/your/sketch/folder]
     libraries
         Ultrasonic
              Ultrasonic.h
              Ultrasonic.cpp
         someotherlibrary
              someotherlibrary.h
```

etc.

Comment: the .h and .cpp of the library can be in src subfolder if 'new' library format is used

Comment: Indeed - thanks for pointing that out. The above should be taken as the minimum basic structure.

Answer (score 0):

i found another library ultrasonic solve my first problem(Ultrasonic.h: No such file or directory) but then have another error... it say(class Ultrasonic' has no member named 'Ranging')....
in this time i changed some of my code and now working good

my code after solve

```
#include <RCSwitch.h> 
#include <Ultrasonic.h>

Ultrasonic ultrasonic(11,10); // (Trig PIN,Echo PIN)
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

int i;

void setup() {
  mySwitch.enableTransmit(4);  
}

void loop() {
Ultrasonic ultrasonic(11,10,3000); // (Trig PIN,Echo PIN, Max.TimeOut in µsec ) 
  mySwitch.send(3000 ,24);
  delay(100); 
}
```